# Go multiplatform library from one package

Tags: go, multiplatform, gomobile

#### The problem

I am trying to create a **multiplatform library**, including **native mobile**, with **Go**.
Using build commands I am able to create different kind formats with various degrees of success.  With **cgo** I can build [.a,.h,.so,.lib,.dll] instead with **gomobile** [.aar,.jar,.framework].

The problem i am facing is that cgo requires that the code of the library is in the main package and gomobile requires that code is on a differrent package than main.

If i try to build the **main** package with **gomobile** I get:

`binding "main" package (golib) is not supported`

Instead if I try to build with **cgo** a package that **isn't** the main one:

`-buildmode=c-shared requires exactly one main package`

or

`-buildmode=c-archive requires exactly one main package`

I am using this commands:

#### Shared library

`go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libraries\golibs.dll`

`go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libraries\golibs.so`

#### Static library

`go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libraries\golibs.lib`

`go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libraries\golibs.a`

#### Android

`gomobile bind -target=android -androidapi 19 -o libraries\mobile\golibs.aar -v .\golibs`

#### Desired Result

How i can **evade duplicate** my library?

I want to have just **one package** (main or not) for my library.